# Spectral theorem for Normal Operators without using $C^*$ Algebras.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

On page $263$  in Conway's book "A Course in Functional Analysis", the spectral theorem for normal operators is stated. It says that if $N$ is a normal operator, there is a unique spectral measure $E$ on the Borel sets of $\sigma(N)$ such that $N = \int z \, dE(z)$, where $z$ is the inclusion map on the spectrum of $N$.
The proof in Conway's book relies upon the theory of $C^*$ algebras, which I want to avoid. Is there a proof that does not use this approach? Can anyone point me to a good source if one exists?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Brian Hall's book *"Quantum Theory for Mathematicians"* (2013): from what I recall his proof of the spectral theorem for bounded self-adjoint operators (Ch.8) as well as the modifications to the proof for the case of normal operators (Theorem 10.20 ff.) avoid technical arguments from $C^*$-algebra theory.